# Android hotspot and Windows 10

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, vpn, android, dell-inspiron

Probably I'm too stupid for this or it's just impossible. So here is the story. Our company got new Dell Laptops (not my choice) and they are meaned for the use outside. Obviously someone needs to connect to some of our files and they need to use a VPN.

- Connecting the laptop to a normal Wi-Fi, everything works.
- Connecting the laptop to an iOS Hotspot, everything works.
- Connecting the laptop to an android Hotspot, nothing what so ever works.

Most of the laptops with windows 10 we tried got this issue and somehow we managed to get it to work on a single Dell Laptop but still it got trouble to connect itself to one of the applications.

Does anyone know why windows 10 literally hates Android Hotspots or what I need to do to make the port available. As I mentioned earlier regular Wi-Fis and iOS hotspots got no issues. I really need help with this issue or ideas on how to solve this because me and my colleague are lost for words and can't find any solution to this issue anywhere.

Comment: All my testing with Android hotspots and Windows 10 tell me this does work. The biggest difference between iOS and Android is that in iOS the hotspot keeps working if you are on the phone, whereas with Android, it stops working when you make a call, and resumes when the call ends. Also some programs will not work when using a mobile hotspot because they have a filter to prevent heavy data usage in order to stop a large phonebill. Outlook is one of such apps.

Comment: funny thing is that my colleague now noticed, that from the iPhone the device gets an adress which is much more diffrent and works while the device get's an adress that is somewhat associated with out network so we are now thinking about getting a mobile 3/4G router which would also be awesome but that will be up to our director to give the OK. :/
Lasttime I asked for one/two he said no because they are useless/not of any use -_-
What a fool. Guess you can relate to something similar, LPChip. Anyway thx for trying